# Graphql queries generated by amplify work well, but throw errors due to auth rules. Why?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-amplify

Summary:
I am using javascript generated by aws-amplify to send queries and mutation to an AWS graphql endpoint with dynamodb backend. The queries/mutations function well enough (they create, get and delete records as intended). But they constantly throw an error in the process:

"Query condition missed key schema element: authorId (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException;"

My code can't be too bad, or else why does it function so well? Still, I would like to get rid of this annoying error, or at least understand it. Why is this error happening?

---

Details:

My api is generated from the exact schema.graphql file provided in the aws-sample "aws-appsync-chat"
https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-appsync-chat

The relevant part of the model is here...

```
type User 
  @model 
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, ownerField: "id", queries: null }]) {
  id: ID!
  username: String!
  conversations: [ConvoLink] @connection(name: "UserLinks")
  messages: [Message] @connection(name: "UserMessages")
    createdAt: String
    updatedAt: String
}
```

Sadly, that sample does not really use queries and mutations generated by amplify. Instead, it uses a hand written schema in the file: src/graphql.js. That's right. Generated queries/mutations are included in the project, but not actually used. This was super disappointing to me. But my faith was restored (somewhat), when I managed to rewrite the javascript logic to make it function (more or less) using queries and mutations that were generated by amplify.

Anyway, the first step I took was to write the logic for (1) querying the users table to see if a record exists already for the currently authroized user, and (2) creating the record if the authorized user is not there. For bonus points, I also wrote logic for (3) deleting the user record from the database.

Working inside a vuejs component, I wrote these methods...

```
methods: {
    async DeleteUserRecord() {
        try {
            let id = store.state.user.username;
            const input = { id: id };
            await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(deleteUser, { input }));// works but throws errors
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('Error deleting user record:', err)
        }
    },
    async GetUserRecord() {
        try {
            let id = store.state.user.username;
            const result = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(getUser, { id }));// works but throws errors
            console.log(result);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('Error getting user record:', err)
        }
    },
    async CreateUserRecord() {
        let username = store.state.user.username;
        try {
            const result = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createUser, { input:{ id:username, username: username } })) // works but throws error
            console.log(result);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('Error creating user record:', err)
        }
    }
  }
```

All three seem to work, but they do throw errors, see attached screenshot for details.

[image: Console errors screenshot]

Always the same error:
"Query condition missed key schema element: authorId (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException;"

The error must be related to the auth rules in the model. But remember that my code does work, so my code is not complete crap.

Can anyone explain this error to me? Is it a bug in AWS? Or is my code written incorrectly?

---------------------------------- UPDATE BELOW -------------------------------

I still do not understand why this error occurs, but I have made some progress in understanding it.

1. As illustrated by the screenshots, the getUser query generated by amplify WILL work if I remove the part that asks for a user's messages.
2. The authorId that appears in the error message must come from the data model of the Message objects.
3. Notice that the graphql schema uses a named connection to link the messages to the user, with a keyField of "authorId".

So, I could probably get rid of the error by fiddling with the specification of the connection in the data model.

But wait. These are the default queries generated by amplify simply by feeding it a schema that comes EXACTLY from an aws-sample project. Shouldn't these queries work well enough without my editing them?

[image: Garphql Schema]
[image: Working Query]
[image: Failing Query]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same issue, as you.

I found the working example in the github https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/pull/1358

```
type Post @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  comments: [Comment] @connection(name: "PostComments", keyField: "postId", sortField: "statusDate")
}

type Comment @model(queries: null) {
  id: ID!
  post: Post! @connection(name: "PostComments", keyField: "postId", sortField: "statusDate")
  postId: ID!
  statusDate: String!
}
```

The KeyField MUST be the same on the both end of @connection attribute. In the example form the github tutorial the missing part is "authorId" from the User type:

```
type User
  @model
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, ownerField: "id", queries: null }]) {
  id: ID!
  username: String!
  conversations: [ConvoLink] @connection(name: "UserLinks")
  messages: [Message] @connection(name: "UserMessages", keyField: "authorId")
  createdAt: String
  updatedAt: String
}
```

Moreover, it would be better to make authorId as an non null value in the Message type, because message cannot be posted without author.

```
type Message @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, ownerField: "authorId" }]) {
  id: ID!
  author: User @connection(name: "UserMessages", keyField: "authorId")
  authorId: String!
  content: String!
  conversation: Conversation! @connection(name: "ConvoMsgs")
  messageConversationId: ID!
  createdAt: String
  updatedAt: String
}
```